# How can i calculate instances based on time

Tags: excel-formula

what will be the formula to show results based on cell value. For example when i enter 30 in cell results will be 1, for 60 results will be 2 and so on. But if entered value will be less then multiple of 30 then result will show divisible of 30 for example if i enter 45 then result should be 1 and for less than 60 but greater than 30 then result should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

use formula =INT(D2/30) where D2 is cell in which you have entered the value